# How to solve an inequality with x and y in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

this is probably a very simple question. How to solve an inequality with `x` and `y` in Jupyter notebook?

For instance:
`0,6x + 0,4y > 0,5x + 0,5y`. The result would be `y<x`.

I've found `solve_univariate_inequality()` but that's just for one variable and the other answers are just too complex involving matrices or examples with too many variables and restrictions.

Comment: Have you had a look at `sympy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned `solve_univariate_inequality`, so I assume that you are using `sympy`. How about using `reduce_inequalities`:

```py
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_inequalities

x, y = Symbol("x"), Symbol("y")
w = reduce_inequalities(0.6*x + 0.4*y > 0.5*x + 0.5*y)

print(w) # y < 1.0*x
```

Found in [SymPy Docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html#sympy.solvers.inequalities.reduce_inequalities).